# Is there terminology of "other things equal"?

Tags: terminology

In economics we use the term "ceteris paribus", which means "other things equal" to examine the cause and effect of specific variables.

Is there any equivalent terminology in physics?

For example, the following statement:

> When water is liquid under a specific range of pressure and temprature,
>   steel is always solid.

If I use economics terminology it becomes:

> When water is liquid, ceteris paribus steel is solid.

Comment: Quite aside from the fact that 'under a specific range of T&P' is in no way saying 'all other things equal', no we don't. To be honest there's not much Latin terminology in physics because the field was developed so recently (aside from Principia which was of course written in Latin). Of course, there's nothing stopping you from using a Latin phrase when it's appropriate, it's just not appropriate in the specific example you gave.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't useful or particularly constructive. The [guidance in meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4063) for terminology questions doesn't really leave much room for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is common.

Some reasons off the top of my head why you wouldn't:

- It isn't clear what is meant by "other things equal" in the physical sense.  What "other things"? Do you have to measure their state at the same time of day as well?  Do they need to be the same mass?  The same colour?!?
- It's non-standard.  Since it is not in common use, it wouldn't be understood immediately; which would *completely* defeat the purpose. You aren't saving time if they have to translate from Latin to understand what you mean.

Generally in physics, it's better to explicitly state what is being done as much as possible.  You don't want your assumptions and setup to be unclear, and you don't want to task your reader with defining Latin terms.  It's easier to just type the few extra characters to make sure you are being specific with what factors are important and what is being held constant.

Comment: I can see now how do you approach situations like my over simplistic example. Just for the record, I am an economics student and somehow my paper's results ended up to support Thermoeconomics ideas, like entropy etc. Therefore, I needed to understand how a physicist would explain a phenomenon. It is clear that you avoid to have assumptions. Thank you